# numpy.core.multiarray failed to import when importing MetaTrader5

Tags: python, python-3.x, metatrader5

I tried to import MetaTrader5 as mt, but the following error is shown:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\\Users\\ESLAM\~1.SOB\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/ipykernel_13712/3445222804.py in \<module\>
\----\> 1 import MetaTrader5 as mt5

\~\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\MetaTrader5\__init_\_.py in \<module\>
255
256 # import C methods to our module
\--\> 257 from .\_core import \*
258
259 # internal order send

ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

Please note that I use jupyter for Python.